# Obtener numero de bits de dos campos simultaneos con bit_length() en SQL

Tags: sql

Como puedo obtener el numero de bits de dos campos en sql con `Bit_Length()`.

Tengo una tabla con cuatro campos de los quiero imprimir todos los campos pero solo dos obtener el numero de bits

id, nombre, cumpleaños y apellidos, quiero los 4 campos pero quiero nombre y apellidos el numero de bits

Answer (score 1):

Si tu `tabla` tuviese los campos: `id`, `nombre`, `apellidos` y `cumple`.

Bastaría con:

```
SELECT id, BIT_LENGTH(nombre), BIT_LENGTH(apellidos), cumple FROM tabla;
```

¿Tienes complicaciones con esa sentencia?